# Embedded C++ interpreter for data manipulation in compiled program

Tags: c++, embedded, interpreter

I have a C++ program, which creates large amount of data stored in standard C++ containers. I would like to be able to launch a C++ interpreter from within my binary program and open a REPL session to manipulate that data. Preferably, I would like to use modern C++11 syntax. Is it feasible? Is it feasible for development in Visual Studio environment?

I've heard about Ch, but it seems to implement only a fraction of C++ 98 syntax.

I've heard about Cling, but if my memory serves me well, one of Cling's top developers answered this question negatively in Google TechTalks 2012. Is that accurate?

Answer (score 1):

There is yet another REPL at your shell prompt. It is bash script which adorn code snippet with usual C++ boilerplate and call compiler.  It has some additional libraries to make it work like AWK and handle ranges/FP expressions.   Not sure if it easy to make it embedded. [Link](http://volnitsky.com/project/scc/).  I know that soon it will have built-in handling of big in memory tables (db-like).  Examples from docs:

```
//  Classic pipe. Alogorithms are from std:: 
scc 'vector<int>{3,1,2,3} | sort | unique | reverse'
{3, 2, 1}

//  Assign 42 to 2..5
scc 'vint V=range(0,9);   range(V/2, V/5) = 42;  V'
{0, 1, 42, 42, 42, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

//  Find (brute force algorithm) maximum of  `cos(x)` in interval: `8 < x < 9`:
scc 'range(8, 9, 0.01) * cos  || max'
-0.1455

//  Integrate sin(x) from 0 to pi
scc 'auto d=0.001;  (range(0,pi,d) * sin || add) * d'
2
```

Comment: Interesting, but it seems to be just a simple C++ expression evaluator. I don't see embedding option and ability to interact with data inside a compiled program.

Answer (score 1):

Although not an interpreter, the [Console](https://github.com/RuntimeCompiledCPlusPlus/RuntimeCompiledCPlusPlus/tree/master/Aurora/Examples/ConsoleExample) from [RuntimeCompiledC++](https://github.com/RuntimeCompiledCPlusPlus/RuntimeCompiledCPlusPlus/wiki) might suite your needs (might need a little effort to getting working as a nicer REPL editor), especially since it uses the systems built-in compiler, you'll be able to get C++11 (though on Windows I'd recommend forcing it to GCC/Clang over MSVC for better C++11 support).

As an added bonus, it'll run quite a bit faster than interpreted code.

Comment: It is an interesting approach, but requires using IDE for REPL session - not a show-stopper, though. The main inconvenience is a need for instrumentation via systems table. There is very little documentation available, so it's hard to assess suitability of RuntimeCompiledCPlusPlus.

Comment: BTW, this made me realize that Edit and Continue mode in Visual Studio could be a crude solution to my problem. Thanks!